# How to Limit PV volume Storage In kuberntes at run time growing

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I could not able to limit PV volume on HOST path in kuberntes.

### YAML:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ include "go-log.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ default "test" .Values.namespace  }}
spec:
  storageClassName: v1
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Mi
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: {{ include "go-log.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ default "test" .Values.namespace  }}
spec:
  limits:
  - type: PersistentVolumeClaim
    max:
      storage: 100Mi
    min:
      storage: 20Mi
```

---

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ include "go-log.fullname" . }}
namespace: {{ default "test" .Values.namespace  }}
labels:
  type: local
spec:
   storageClassName: v1
   persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
capacity:
   storage: 50Mi

accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
hostPath:
    path: {{ default "/home/app_data" .Values.go_pv.path  }}
```

But I need to limit the pv during Runtime Like(POD should Evit if it crosses certain limit or storage in PV or PVC on HOSTPATH )

I have written go-application which will write log files to mount dir /home/app_data. which i could not control Volume Storage  in kubernetes at RUNTIME

Comment: I verified that API for PV, limit is not a valid field. You can check the following documentation [1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#persistentvolumespec-v1-core) [2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#limitrangeitem-v1-core) [3](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/) to confirm.

Comment: But https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/limit-storage-consumption/ . shows we do have limit field on Storage.

Comment: I understand that LimitRange is supported field. However, limit is not supported in your third yaml file under 'kind: PersistentVolume'. You can find examples in this official Kubernetes [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

Comment: my issue is  why Limit Range  limit is not evicting the pod when it crosses max storage. As i know those fields are during  request phase....   Do we have any run time limits regarding PV-PVC limits in host Path bear metal which should evict pod when it crosses limits.

Comment: that's not what Limit Range is for, the limit range resource determines what the range of storage capacity you allow PVCs to request. It is not like limits that pods use. Your storage will simply fill up.